# How should I interpret the Android Developers ViewModel lifecycle diagram?

Tags: android-lifecycle, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel

The following diagram appears in the [Android Jetpack ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel):
[image: ViewModel lifecycle diagram]

Why does the upper `onDestroy` graphic in the middle column have a pointy end and not terminate the `ViewModel Scope` while the other `onDestroy` graphic has a square end and terminate the `ViewModel Scope`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get in touch with the creator of the diagram, Jose Alcérreca, who told me "the second `onDestroy` doesn't have an arrow is because it's the end of the activity's lifecycle (triggered by `finish()` not a recreation)."

I was also pointed to the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/ComponentActivity.java;l=246) for `ComponentActivity`, which shows the observer for `ON_DESTROY`:

```
    getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleEventObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source,
                @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
                // Clear out the available context
                mContextAwareHelper.clearAvailableContext();
                // And clear the ViewModelStore
                if (!isChangingConfigurations()) {   // ***
                    getViewModelStore().clear();     // ***
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

As the starred lines show, the `clear()` method is called for the `ViewModelStore` only if the call to `onDestroy()` is **not** due to a configuration change.